# Execute custom filename with PHP (via Apache)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

On my development machine, this works as expected (requests to `server.com/.myhandler` are executed as php), but when I uploaded to the production machine (running ubuntu server 11.04) it just serves the un-executed php. Is there anything extra I must configure for this to work?

Contents of `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType text/html .myhandler
<FilesMatch "\.myhandler$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex .myhandler index.php index.htm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most possibly this type of configuration is not allowed via `.htaccess` in the directory where your script and .htaccess reside in. Put this in your Apache site / VirtualHost configuration:

```
<Directory /absolute/path/to/webroot/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```